# How to keep the scale consistent among multiple plots when using geom_sf()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made series of plots, and the range of values differs from plot to plot, so the scales among plots are different from one to another. I'm trying to keep the scale consistent(from 0 to 130000), so I set midpoint=6500, but it seems that it does not work.

```
 for (i in 2016:2018){
   for (m in 1:12){
       yourfilename=paste(i,m,".jpg",sep="") 
       jpeg(file=yourfilename, width =800, height = 700)

       product_by_month<- data_all%>%
       filter(year==i & month==m)

       product_2010_map<-c_map%>%
       left_join(product_by_month,by=c("name"="city"))

       pp<-ggplot(data=product_2010_map,aes(fill=amt)) + 
           theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
                 plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
                 axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                 axis.text=element_blank())+
           geom_sf()+
           scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", high = "blue",
                                midpoint=6500)
      print(pp)
      dev.off()  
  }
}
```

Comment: The color scale?  Or the y/horizontal scale?

Comment: It's not related to your question, consider using [`ggsave()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html).  Also, [`facet_grid()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) may fix your scale problem, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @wibeasley  The color scale. And dpseidel's answer works. :)

Answer (score 5):

You likely want `scale_fill_gradient` instead of `scale_color_gradient` given you are mapping your `amt` variable to the `fill` rather than `color` argument. Additionally, you need not use `scale_fill_gradient2` unless you want to specify a third mid color. Once you are using the correct scale, you can set the limits of the scale explicitly using the limits argument:

```
... + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue",
                            limits = c(0,130000))
```

Once set, the scale will be the same for all of your plots no matter the range of the data plotted.